# Web Browser MultiThreded Casting Exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, browser

Up till now I had a single threaded app that crawled web sites.
Because I want to make it faster, I tried rebuilding to a multihreaded  app.
this is what i do:
I have a Crawl Class, that hold a WebBrowser object.
This is how I start the thread:

```
 Crawler c1 = new Crawler();  
 Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(c1.Crawl));  
 t1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 t1.start()
```

The threads arrive to this functions:

```
 LogIn(bool isInit)  
 {  
   browser = new WebBrowser();
   NavigateAndWaitForLoad(browser, "http://www.someurl.com", 1000);
   HtmlElement elemEmail = (HtmlElement)browser.Document.GetElementById("email");  
  }



 void NavigateAndWaitForLoad(WebBrowser wb, string link, int waitTime)  
  {  
   wb.Navigate(link);
   int count = 0;
   while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)  
   {  
    Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeMiliseconds);
    Application.DoEvents();
    count++;
    if (count > waitTime / sleepTimeMiliseconds)
        break;  
    }
```

Now in the single threaded it works great,
However in the mutlithreded app it crashes on this line:
 HtmlElement elemEmail = (HtmlElement)browser.Document.GetElementById("email");
with the exception of illegal casting???!!!
have no idea why?
please help...

Comment: illegal casting? and what is the actual type of `browser.Document.GetElementById("email")`? can you look up in the debugger?

Comment: well, then the cast should not fail, right?

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917547/webbrowser-control-does-not-render-html

Answer (score 1):

You're using the WebBrowser object, Application.DoEvents, and Thread.Sleep. Bad, bad, bad. You're asking for trouble here.

Suggestion:

If you're just building a web crawler, just use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to download web pages as a string. Then, if you need to parse it into an HTML document, use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

This way, you can avoid using the web browser UI control, you can avoid doing Thread.Sleep, you can avoid the accidental recursion-inducing Application.DoEvents.

Here's a sample:

```
public async void DownloadWebPage(string address)
{
    using(var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var webPageContents = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync();

        // Woohoo, we have the contents of the web page. Do anything with it...
        Console.WriteLine(webPageContents);
    }
}

// Usage:
DownloadWebPage("http://www.google.com");
```